# Selecting multiple relationships in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have table `BaseTable` which has the list `Categories` (`Category` table). `Categories` have a list of `Definitions` (`Definition` table), `Definitions` have a list of `Values` (`Value` table) and `Definitions` table *also* has a list of `Commands` (`Commands` table).

Below is the table structure:

```
BaseTable: Categories -> Definitions -> Values -> Comments
BaseTable: Categories -> Definitions -> Commands
```

So I want to retrieve a row from `BaseTable` along with related tables.

This is the code snippet I used to retrieved the data from the tables:

```
BaseTable base = base.dbcontext.BaseTables
    .Include(b1 => b1.Categories.Select(c => c.Definitions
                                        .Select(v => v.Values
                                        .Select(com => com.Comments))))
    .Include(b2=>b2.Categories.Select(k=>k.Definitions
                                       .Select(f=>f.Commands))) 
    .Where(b3 => b3.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();
```

Using above query I was able to retrieve the all the related tables for `BaseTable`. But in my database I have lot of entries in `Values` and `Commands` tables, so this query is taking lot of time to retrieve all the data.

Can anyone please help me in writing the correct query to retrieve the above scenario?

Comment: Could anyone please let me know the resolution for above issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try lazy loading by adding the ‘virtual’ keyword to the properties in your model. In many cases it will improve the performance of your application.

Comment: Lazy loading and improved performance are hardly ever correlated. On the contrary.